# Is it possible to allow selection of multiple values in rich:combobox?

Tags: combobox, richfaces

Is it possible to allow selection of multiple values in rich:combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible if you use it out of the box.

Try JSF's `h:selectManyListBox` if it is suitable in your case.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually using it... Just wanted to make sure if there's no way to do that with combo..